# Problem of Real analysis, continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Problem: Let $f$: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, growing funtion and $D(f)=\{t \in \mathbb{R} : f $ is not continuous in $t \}$. Show that:

a) Exist $q: D(f) \to \mathbb{Q}$ such that for all $t \in D(f)$ : $f(t-)<q(t)<f(t+)$

b) "q" is injective, and $D(f)$ at most numerable.

Idea: I know that you must use the principle that: between two real numbers must be a rational number. Also that $\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite-countable set.

Comment: Hint: Since $f$ is growing, $f(t+)\geq f(t-)$, and if $f(t+)=f(t-)$, then $t\not\in D(f)$.

Comment: What exactly is $f (t+) $ and $f (t-) $?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is asking you to show that a monotone function is discontinuous at at most countably many points. It follows from the fact that if $f$ is discontinuous at $t$, then $\lim_{x\to t^-}f(x):=f(t-)$ and $\lim_{x\to t^+}f(x):=f(t+)$ exist, and $f(t-)<f(t+)$.

From this, for any positive integer $n$, $f(x)\leqslant f(n)$ for all $x\leqslant n$, and so if there were uncountably many points $x_\alpha<n$ at which $f$ were discontinuous, then
$$f(n) \geqslant \sum_{\alpha}(f(x_\alpha+)-f(x_\alpha-)) = +\infty,$$
a contradiction (the sum of an uncountable quantity of positive numbers is infinite). Hence $D(f)\cap(-\infty,n)$ is countable, and $$D(f)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D(f)\cap(-\infty,n)$$ is countable as the countable union of countable sets.